# ParseUser : Cannot use object of type __PHP_Incomplete_Class as array

Tags: php, parse-platform

I want to use Parse to save data.
I use ParseUser to save users.
Documentation [here](https://parse.com/docs/php/guide#users).

When I make this I have a ParseUser object :

```
    $user = new \Parse\ParseUser();
    $user->set("username", "my name");
    $user->set("password", "my pass");
    $user->set("email", "email@example.com");
    var_dump($user);
    exit();
```

But if I try to use signUp method.
Documentation [here](https://www.parse.com/docs/php/guide#users-signing-up).

Like this :

```
        $user = new \Parse\ParseUser();
    $user->set("username", "my name");
    $user->set("password", "my pass");
    $user->set("email", "email@example.com");

    try {
        $user->signUp();
    } catch (\Parse\ParseException $ex) {
        echo $ex->getMessage();
    }

    exit();
```

I have this message :

> object(__PHP_Incomplete_Class)#1 (11) { ["__PHP_Incomplete_Class_Name"]=> string(15) "Parse\ParseUser" ["_sessionToken":protec.....
>   Fatal error: Cannot use object of type __PHP_Incomplete_Class as array in /var/www/myproject/vendor/parse/php-sdk/src/Parse/ParseUser.php on line 340

Answer (score 3):

I find the error :

```
require './vendor/autoload.php';
```

must be BEFORE

```
if (session_status() == PHP_SESSION_NONE) {
    session_start();
}
```